# How to parameterize agent pool name in azure pipeline with yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Hi I am using agent pool in azure pipeline, so i have multiple agents so i want to parameterize the pool name like shown below but when i do this i get an error as (Line: 11, Col: 9): A template expression is not allowed in this context

```
parameters:
  - name: pool_name
    displayName: agent pool location
    type: string
    default: test-ashish

trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: ${{parameters.pool_name}}
  demands: 
  - Location -equals EASTUS2

steps:
- script: |
    echo "This job is only for testing"
    echo $()
  name: Test_Job
  displayName: Test Job
```

Comment: Check if this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698996/azure-devops-is-it-possible-to-nest-yaml-templates-inside-another-yaml-template

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by using the answer in this issue: [Azure Devops: Is it possible to nest yaml templates inside another yaml template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698996/azure-devops-is-it-possible-to-nest-yaml-templates-inside-another-yaml-template).

**Copyed from link:**
refer code:

```
parameters:
  buildArtifactName: "build"
  solution: ""

jobs:
- job: 'BuildSolution'
  pool:
    vmImage: ${{parameters.vmImage}}
    continueOnError: false
  variables:
    artifactName: ${{ parameters.buildArtifactName}}
  steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: ${{ parameters.solutionDir }}/${{ parameters.solution }}
        configuration: ${{parameters.buildConfiguration}}
```